# Scrapy: overwrite DEPTH_LIMIT variable based on value read from custom config

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `InitSpider` and read a custom `json` configuration within the `def __init__(self, *a, **kw):` method.

The json config file contains a directive with which I can control the crawling depth. I can already successfully read this configuration file and extract the value. The main problem is how to tell scrapy to use this value.

Note: I dont want to use a command line argument such as `-s DEPTH_LIMIT=3`, I actually want to parse it from my custom configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DEPTH_LIMIT` is used in [`scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py). As you might have had a quick look at the code, you'll see that the `DEPTH_LIMIT` value is read only when initializing that middleware.

I think this might be a good solution to you:

1. In the `__init__` method of your spider, set a spider attribute `max_depth` with your custom value.
2. Override `scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware` and have it check the `max_depth` attribute.
3. Disable the default `DepthMiddleware` and enable your own one in the settings.

See also http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

A quick example of the overridden middleware described in step #2:

```
class MyDepthMiddleware(DepthMiddleware):

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
    if hasattr(spider, 'max_depth'):
        self.maxdepth = getattr(spider, 'max_depth')
    return super(MyDepthMiddleware, self).process_spider_output(response, result, spider)
```

Comment: where do I save the middleware class and what filename should I give it?

Comment: I solved the above issue. It does work now, however it seems that pages with a depth > max_depth are still crawled (downloaded), but not processed. Is it also possible to not download them in the first place in order to save time and bandwidth?